# Zwei Verben mit zwei direkten Objekten in einem Satz

Tags: translation, verb, accusative

Where do I put the accusative object for each verb in a sentence with two verbs?

For example, is this sentence correct?

```
you need him to buy him something
du brauchst ihn etwas zu kaufen ihn
```

or should I say

```
du brauchst ihn ihn etwas zu kaufen
```

or

```
du brauchst ihn etwas ihn zu kaufen
```

Comment: The English construction has no direct German counterpart, all of your attempts are wrong. Expand it into a construction with a relative clause and try to translate that.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer now it comes to my mind to ask why so? is it because of the zu infinitive construction? I mean can we say that zu infinitive construction doesn't accept accusative objects? thanks again in advance

Comment: To clarify, who is supposed to buy something in the example?

Comment: Are your examples whole sentences? Would you then write them as such?

Answer (score 4):

The correct way would be:

> Du brauchst ihn, um ihm etwas zu kaufen.

translated directly from English.
*to buy him something* and *um ihm etwas zu kaufen* are infinitive constructions in both languages. German needs the comma here, however.

Comment: Except that that does not mean the same as the English sentence was probably intended to mean.

Comment: @CarstenS Absent more context and assuming the English sentence is correct, I don't see, what's wrong with it.

Comment: I think we will need @Iván to clarify what exactly he meant. (See how I used *need*? This is how I understood it in the question, which is, I think, different from your translation.)